# Smartgit precommit fails: incompatible node version

Tags: node.js, nvm, pre-commit-hook, smartgit, husky

When I try to commit a change using SmartGit client I get the following error:

```
The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "12.x". Got "14.15.1"
error Commands cannot run with an incompatible environment.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

Which is weird 'cause my currently active node version (selected with `nvm`) is compatible with the expected version. This is what I get in my terminal:

```
 % nvm current
v12.21.0
```

If I try to commit the same change from the command line everything works fine.
How can I tell SmartGit to use the current active version?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question but I still had the very same issue today and I solved followuing the official troubleshooting
https://typicode.github.io/husky/troubleshooting.html#command-not-found

You need a `~/.huskyrc` (in your user's home, not in the root of the project) with the following content

```
# This loads nvm.sh, sets the correct PATH before running hook, and ensures the project version of Node
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"

[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"

# If you have an .nvmrc file, we use the relevant node version
if [[ -f ".nvmrc" ]]; then
  nvm use
fi
```